# How to create python2.7 environment by virtualenv?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python on MacOS and I have a problem to setup a python2.7 environment. I have installed both python2.7 and python3.6 on the system. And run below code to setup python2.7 env. I am not sure why I get this error. From the output I see it is using `/anaconda/lib/python3.6` directory. How can I make it to use `python2.7` environment?

```
$ virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 venv/
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2.7
New python executable in /Users/joey/dev/jump/jump-api/venv/bin/python2.7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2869, in <module>
    main()
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 925, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1231, in install_python
    copy_exe_shared_libs_and_symlinks(executable, py_executable, home_dir)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2828, in copy_exe_shared_libs_and_symlinks
    of = codefile(f, rpaths)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2799, in codefile
    return machofile(file, list(initial_rpaths_transitive))
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2422, in __init__
    _, sos = zip(*mach_o_find_dylibs(file))
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2386, in mach_o_find_dylibs
    do_file(ofile, find_lc_load_dylib, offset_size(), results, regex)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 2355, in do_file
    do_file(file, offset_size(offset, size), *args)
TypeError: do_file() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: You are using Anaconda... Have you seen the [documentations](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html)?

Comment: How can I use virtualenv instead of Anaconda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you already have Anaconda installed, you can create a Python virtual environment by executing the following command in the terminal-

```
conda create -n pythonenvname python=x.x anaconda
```

Because you are trying to create a Python 2.7 virtual environment, I would suggest you using `python27` as your environment name for convenience. Moreover, `x.x` refers to the version of Python that would be used to create the environment. In your case, it's `2.7`.

So this is the command you should run to set up your virtual environment-

```
conda create -n python27 python=2.7 anaconda
```

After you have installed the environment, run the following command to activate it-

```
source activate python27
```

Now, if you run any python command, for example, `python helloworld.py`, then the Python 2.7 interpreter would be used.

To deactivate the Python environment and return to your default one, simply execute the following command-

```
source deactivate
```

For further reference, check out [this site](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/).